# Estimating sample variance

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, estimation

Suppose that we have 2 independent samples $X_{11}, X_{12},.., X_{1n_1}$ and $X_{21}, X_{22},.., X_{2n_2}$ from a normally distributed population with $n_1<n_2$. Does that mean that the sample variance of the first sample is more efficient in the estimation of the population variance, versus the sample variance of the second sample?

Comment: If you were to use only the first $n_1$ elements of the second sample, how efficient would that be compared to using the first sample?  Now draw your conclusions.

Comment: Well, I suppose that the sample variance of the second sample is more efficient.